# how to get the count of a number in a List PARI/GP

Tags: list, count, pari, pari-gp

is there a method to get the count of a given number in a List? I have a List for which I want to verify, that no number is more than x-times in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For input being list of integers, you can use the `matreduce`. It returns the 2-column matrix. Its first column will contain the unique elements of your input list. The second column will contain the counts. See the example below.

```
> x = [1,2,1,1,2,2,2,3,1,2,1,3];
> M = matreduce(x)
[1 5]
[2 5]
[3 2]
```

So, just review the second column to ensure that no its element is more than `N`-times.

```
> N = 4;
> #select(elt -> elt > N, M[,2])  % count the numbers greater than N.
2
```